# Convert hashed values from database to readable string

Tags: c#, sql-server, hash

I'm working on a small project to get familiar with C#/.NET. I'm trying to authenticate a user that's on the Users table on a local SQL server via a form. The passwords are hashed (not salted - Only testing). My problem is I'm not sure how to convert the hashed password value (SHA512) that's in the database to a string. Should I be using a different approach to this?

From what I'm reading, I think I have to use the Convert.ToBase64String method, but I'm not sure how I'd approach it or if I'm on the right track. Here's what I have.

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=myLocalSQLServer;Initial Catalog=libtest;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter sqa = new SqlDataAdapter("Select count(*) from Users where UserName = '"+ UserName.Text +"' and Password = '"+ Password.Text +"'",con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sqa.Fill(dt);


        if(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login Successful!");

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username or Password is incorrect");
        }
```

The hashed passwords are not able to authenticate. I'd like to be able to authenticate the hashed passwords and validate users to connect to the next form.

Comment: Please read up on Parameterized Sql Statements. Without them, you are vulnerable to Sql Injection attacks. It's never too early to consider security, even if you're just starting to learn or this is a quick application.

Comment: What is the datatype of the Sql column in your database?

Comment: Don't query the users table based on the password, instead, retrieve the user by username, hash the provided password and compare that hash with the one retrieved before.

Comment: Hashing is a one way process. You shouldn't be trying to turn the hashed value back into a string, you should be getting the salt from the database, hashing it in your application (using said salt) and then checking that value against the database's to check if it matches the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your password is already hashed in the database, so you have to compare the hashed value stored in the database and the hashed value entered by the user. Look at the example below.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SHA512Cng sha = new SHA512Cng();
        var hash = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Password_field.Password));
        var hexSignature = ToHexString(hash);
    }

    public static string ToHexString(byte[] array)
    {
        return string.Concat(Array.ConvertAll(array, b => b.ToString("x2")));
    }
```